# How to clear frames of player without clearing all the other rectangles

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

How can I clean the canvas without actually clearing everything I have drawn.Probably there is something wrong with the design of this program.I simply want to make the rectangle fall(I’ll fully animate it later) without clearing the rectangles drawn with the mouse.I tried to use c.clearRect(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height) but it doesn’t work (and I don’t know why).

```
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
var c = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
// class drawn rectangles
class Rectangle{
    constructor(x,y,width,height,is_solid){
        this.x = x;
        this.y= y;
        this.width=width;
        this.height = height;
        this.is_solid = false;
    }
    draw(x,y){
        c.fillStyle = "red";
        c.fillRect(x, y, 30, 30);
        this.is_solid = true;
        tiles_array.push(this);
    }
}
// tiles array and tile object
let tiles_array = [];
let tile = new Rectangle();

//mouse object 
var mouse = {
    key_move: window.addEventListener('mousemove',(event)=>{
        mouse.x = event.clientX;
        mouse.y= event.clientY;
    }),
    key_click: canvas.addEventListener('click',()=>{
            tile.draw(mouse.x, mouse.y);
        })
}


class Player{
    constructor(x,y,width,height,collision){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.collision = collision;
    }
    draw(){
        c.fillStyle = "green";
        c.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    }
}
let player = new Player(200,50,20,40,false);

// main function
 function main(){

    mouse.key_move;
    mouse.key_click;
    player.y += 10;
    // first clear canvas then draw
    
    player.draw();
    
    requestAnimationFrame(main);
}
requestAnimationFrame(main);
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a nice way to do that. My way would be to clear the screen, and then re-draw everything every frame.

```
// first clear canvas then draw
ctx.fillStyle="black";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,4000,4000);


tile.draw();
player.draw();
```

Canvas is just like a 2D image. It uses bitmap, doesn't have layers unlike html, and once you've drawn over something its gone.